# store data using onchange

Tags: javascript, html

> How do I store data using onchange in input tag?

This is my html:

```
<form action="store.php" method="POST"
     <input type="text" name="distribution" id="distro" value="8%" onClick="this.select();" onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
     <select name="Q1" id="Q1" onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option> 
         <option value="2">2</option>  
         <option value="3">3</option>  
         <option value="4">4</option>  
         <option value="5">5</option>   
     </select>
     <select name="E2" id="E2" onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option> 
         <option value="2">2</option>  
         <option value="3">3</option>  
         <option value="4">4</option>  
         <option value="5">5</option>   
     </select>
     <select name="T3" id="T3" onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
         <option value="0">0</option>
         <option value="1">1</option> 
         <option value="2">2</option>  
         <option value="3">3</option>  
         <option value="4">4</option>  
         <option value="5">5</option>   
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="A4" placeholder="A4" id="A4" disabled onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
     <input type="text" name="Ave" placeholder="Ave" id="Ave" disabled onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
     <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

This is my javascript:

```
function calc(Q1id,E2id,T3id,distroid,A4id,Aveid){
    var Q1 = parseInt(document.getElementById(Q1id).value);
    var E2 = parseInt(document.getElementById(E2id).value);
    var T3 = parseInt(document.getElementById(T3id).value);
    var distro = parseInt(document.getElementById(distroid).value);
    var result = parseFloat(distro)/100;

    var ratingAve = document.getElementById(A4id).value = parseFloat(Math.round(Q1+E2+T3)/3).toFixed(2);

    document.getElementById(Aveid).value = parseFloat(ratingAve*result).toFixed(2);
```

}

I want them to store it into my database but when I click save, only distribution, Q1, E2, and T3 have data while A4 and Ave do not have data. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the text input, use 'readonly' instead of 'disabled'.

```
<input type="text" name="A4" placeholder="A4" id="A4" readonly onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
<input type="text" name="Ave" placeholder="Ave" id="Ave" readonly onchange="calc('Q1','E2','T3','distro','A4','Ave')">
```

Comment: Thank you so much :D Godbless :D

Answer (score 0):

Because you disabled it.
Remove **disabled**

Or If you want to disable it to show.
Add another hidden input for form submit.

```
<input type="hidden" name="Name" id="Name" />
```